# transferring funds from bittrex to binance

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, bitcoin-wallet-app, bittrex, binance

I want transfer a btc from bittrex to binance but they are telling me that they are supporting only non segwit adress. I don’t know if my btc adress In binance it’s non segwit too.   Thank u

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if an address is a segwit address?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this question under the assumption that you are asking how to tell whether an address is a segwit address.

Judging from some Reddit threads I've found, Bittrex does not support withdrawing to *native* segwit addresses. Native segwit addresses start with the prefix `bc1…`. If the deposit address you got from Binance starts either with `1…` or with `3…` and Bittrex accepts it in their withdrawal request form, you should be fine. If it does start with `bc1…` look whether there is some option on Binance to switch the address format for the deposit address.

Comment: Thank u for responding. My btc adress in binance it’s starting by 1Pn. it’s good ? And an other thing I tried before with the btc adress in binance (ERC20) and it stayed pending for hours and when I looked in the blockchain I didn’t find the the same amount that I sent. So I was little scared to lost it, then I canceled the transaction.

Comment: An address starting with `1Pn…` would be a non-segwit address and should work for a withdrawal from Bittrex. Do not use the ERC20 address, ERC20 is a standard for tokens on Ethereum.